# Might I ever get Question Limit Banned?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I have a hefty number of questions, some very popular and others growing. Do I ever need to fear a question ban on this particular site?

Comment: Maybe, if you posted a string of 30 poor questions averaging -5 in downvotes.  I think it has something to do with the quality of one questions in the most recent n weeks or months, but that's a guess, and I have no clue as to what $n$ might be.  I say this, because a person can have had $99.5$ percent of their flags deemed "helpful", but over a 7 day period, if declines on one's flages overwhelm those deemed helpful, one may be banned from flagging for a period of time.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks just asking cause I know there are question bans I am almost at 100 if not at 100 questions. So I am just wondering about that.

Comment: Bottom line, the key here is consistency.  Over the course of a week, One poor post with two downvotes and that others delete, plus 7 upvoted questions, is not a problem.  It's when one reveals a *pattern* of posting low quality posts that one is in trouble.  But indeed, higher rep users have more of a "pattern" established than do  newer users.

Comment: No need to worry, EnlightenedFunky.

Comment: You can somewhat self-evaluate your quality-ban statistic: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/885476/am-i-quality-banned-for-questions?negdel=0&closedel=0&deleted=0&UserId=372659 if you know your deleted questions. Based on what is visible you're way above the Q-ban so unless you now start posting utterly bad questions that all get downvoted into oblivion I doubt you can manage to get into a Q-ban. I also believe reputation is factored in (as in above a certain rep you can't get Q-banned) but that is only hearsay and I don't know the exact cut-off.

Answer (score 7):

There are two things to keep apart:

- There are automatic questions bans that are based on the quality, or rather the reception, of the questions. If all, or at least most, of your questions are well-received you will not run into this. Here, well-received mostly means not negatively received. It's not necessary to have a great score. Not having a negative score and not getting closed and deleted suffices.
- There are rate limits for most every action on the site. Even if you asked the best questions there were you cannot ask hundred of them in a day. The limit is  is six a day and fifty over thirty days. Users with few point also cannot ask questions in rapid successions.

For more details see [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

Comment: Thanks for this.  Especially pointing out that "rate limits" are different than being banned from asking questions.