# I would like to get out of question ban

Tags: support, post-ban

I did my best to edit my questions and fix them up. I would like to get out of the ban

I realize when I post I have trouble getting through to everyone and many times it comes back by biting me on the arse and l get downvoted. I am an autodidact when it comes to topology,so things that might be obvious to you, might not be to me. I am 59 and graduated long ago

Comment: I am not really sure whether the tag ([meta-tag:specific-question]) fit here. See [the tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-question/info) for some information about this tag and when it should be used.

Comment: Ok I deleted it. @Martin Sleziak

Comment: This won't help with the question ban, but I still want to point out that there are various chatrooms around here: [List of chatrooms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26814). In particular, if you have a short question, maybe asking in chat could be sometimes worth trying. (I have noticed that there are several questions asking for proof verification.) Based on your questions, possibly you might be interested in the rooms [General topology](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/15201/general-topology) and [Set theory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2318/set-theory).

Comment: You can see that those rooms are not visited very often. (OTOH they are focused on a single area.) If you want a room that has many users, the [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics) might be a reasonable choice.

Comment: One remark: please avoid posting links to illegal copies of books. I saw this on two of your answers. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4681/is-sharing-books-ok

Comment: I didn’t know it was illegal

Comment: @Eudoxus If the copyright on some work has not expired (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries%27_copyright_lengths)), and you are not the copyright holder, then you have no right to share or republish it. That it's available on some web site does not make it legal. Unless it's the web site of the copyright holder, of course: some authors publish a copy of their book online, usually with the permission of the editor. Then it's ok to share the link (but it's not necessarily ok to republish the book on another web site).

Comment: Ok l thought they had the right

Comment: @Eudoxus They haven't. There is also a lending service on the Internet Archive, that is also highly criticized (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Library#Copyright_violation_accusations) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Archive#Open_Library)), but there is little doubt that publishing a downloadable pdf copy of an in-copyright book is illegal in most countries. However there are also many books with expired copyright in the Archive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get out of a question ban?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27815/how-can-i-get-out-of-a-question-ban).  More dupes listed below the duplicating answer.

Comment: I would really like to help you: To get out of a question ban, you have to work to make each question you have posted better by editing and formatting. If you can ask advice for how to make a specific question better, then it'd be easier to answer.

Comment: I have edited some of my worst questions and have given a proof based off remarks

Comment: I am out of it now.thanx

Comment: Not anymore,back on the ban. I re-edited most of posts and did everything I can @Burian

Comment: After my last post was badly received,with -7,l got a message from MSE stating I was in danger of being banned unless l fixed up certain posts. So for the last one, I made tons of them to avoid being banned.Obviously,it didn’t help… Members thought I was a busing the system. I was conforming with it to being banned @amWhy

Answer (score 5):

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/1052107)

> Automatic bans never expire or "time out". This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to freely post again. The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways. Mods can't help also.

What can you do?

- Focusing on improving old question instead of new ones

As you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/837396/eudoxus?tab=questions&sort=votes) some of your questions are lacking [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/876009) like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3944809/876009). In some question you have used MathJax but only in some maths tools try to use it for more tools.

- Do not delete your question

Like I have described [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33990/876009) one should try to edit his question to make it better instead of deleting it. In case you have deleted your question until it is not total spam undeleted them if deleted by you alone and if it is deleted by other users with [delete privelege](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) just try to edit the question. In case you felt you have given your best and it is not undeleted yet ask for feedback over [here in Constructive Feedback Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback) or ask for feedback to undelete in [CURED chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured).

Some special points-

- If you're blocked from asking questions and are unable to improve your existing questions (or your existing questions are all deleted), you'll get the chance to post one new question 6 months after your last question. Your block will still remain once that question is posted, but a single positively-received question could be enough to lift you out of the block. (This does not apply to answer bans.)
- If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted [might enable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68885/1052107) you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure.

You can know more about question and answer ban and how to get out from that ban through [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/1052107)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of many math.se meta posts.  Please search meta.math.se for dupes before saying what's already been said on this site, many times.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16909/i-have-been-put-under-a-question-ban?r=SearchResults&s=2|52.6300, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27815/how-can-i-get-out-of-a-question-ban?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31356/might-i-ever-get-question-limit-banned?r=SearchResults&s=5|39.2294, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30411/why-have-i-been-banned-from-asking-questions?r=SearchResults&s=7|35.6150